# Rails 4 AR .select includes pk field in result even if result is grouped (as opposed to Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm migrating my app from Rails 3.2 to 4.0, and I'm finding a number of broken tests because Rails 4 includes the PK field (usually 'id') in the result set when using something like:

```
Invoice.where(cust_id: 1234).select('sum(gross) as gross, sum(tax) as tax, sum(net) as net').to_a.first.attributes
```

This used to return `{'gross' => 1000.00, 'tax' => 0.00, 'net' => 1000.00}` in 3.2, but in 4.0 it returns `{'gross' => 1000.00, 'tax' => 0.00, 'net' => 1000.00, id => nil}`

This is a problem if you're writing tests and comparing actual results to expected results, in which case the id field throws off comparisons. I don't see this change in behavior documented anywhere. Is there a way to turn this "feature" off?

Comment: I’m not sure about turning this ‘feature’ off, but you can add `.except(‘id’)` to your query(s). Hopefully you don’t have too many queries.

Comment: You need to adjust tests in response to API changes in rails. Once I had to change about 4K test case migrating from 2.3 to 3.2.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, hashrocket.

Comment: Amit Patel I recognize that that is the case. My issue is I found this not through the documentation, but through experimentation. I've searched the documentation and found no mention of this difference. I'm wondering if there's other documentation that I'm not looking at that might tell me other differences that I can address pro-actively instead of waiting until they break a test or worse, break my code in production.